# I have a Safari publicity issue?

Tags: mac, safari, youtube

I downloaded an app for "watching FREE online tv shows" and obviously the app didn't worked, so I uninstall this app and now every time I click on any link in safari (most of the times in youtube) i get a new tab with publicity.

Im really worried about this because its something new for me, I can't find a solution, I installed an ad block from safari extensions and restored safari and nothing works.

Please help me!

Thanks.

PS. If you need screenshots, log indo or something let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've downloaded adware and possibly malware onto your computer. You'll need to remove it.

To check for adware, try AdwareMedic:

http://www.adwaremedic.com/

For malware removal, ClamXav is a free and effective choice:

http://www.clamxav.com/

Good luck with the cleanup!